# How do I get shifts for a specific user using MSGraph API and Shfits for Teams

Tags: .net, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get the shifts for a user within the given date. I've gotten the given date to work but I can't get the specific user part to work.

```
    private async Task<IEnumerable<Shift>> GetShiftsAsync(string start, string end, string userId)
    {
        var shifts = await _graphClient.Teams[TEAMID].Schedule.Shifts.Request()
            .Filter($"contains(userId,{userId})")
           .GetAsync();
        return shifts;
    }
```

This results in a Bad Request for an "Invalid filter clause"

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  Status Code: BadRequest
  Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: BadRequest
  Message: Invalid filter clause
```

I have also tried

```
Filter($"userId eq {userId}")
```

With the same result

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue is resolved with the below answer?

Comment: it did not but it gave me a way forward. I'm not sure if this object supports filtering with the userId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link may help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter

I normally build a filterString. Maybe you could try something like below.

```
var filterString = $"filter(userId, '{userId}')";

private async Task<IEnumerable<Shift>> GetShiftsAsync(string start, string end, string userId)
    {
        var shifts = await _graphClient.Teams[TEAMID].Schedule.Shifts.Request()
            .Filter(filterString)
           .GetAsync();
        return shifts;
    }
```

Comment: that's a good idea to use the filter string I built the string and got a 

Message: The entity property 'userId' is not allowed in $filter query.

but that's a much better problem than having just an invalid request

Comment: [Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6296)  looks like Microsoft just doesn't support filtering by userId on Shifts objects.

Comment: @averybusinesssolutions - As mentioned in the Github issue filter is not supported on userId property. You can raise this suggestion on [Microsoft Uservoice](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)